# Vertical Text-overflow on table cell

Tags: css

```
   .table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  }
  .text-overflow {
  display:block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }

  .cell-4 {
  width: 200px;
  }
```

https://codepen.io/mstone6769/pen/dodJEz

how to make it vertical overflow on table cell?
i try to use overflow-y but didnt work

Comment: i think you need to give style `width: 200px;` to your `.text-overflow` and your code will be work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to allow text to wrap inside `.text-overflow` updated css

```
.text-overflow {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `overflow: scroll`.

```css
.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  /* Just for the example */
}

.text-overflow {
  display: block;
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.cell-4 {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Text overflow in a table cell</h1>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td class="cell-4">
          <span class="text-overflow">Ccell 4 is really really long and needs to wrap because it's so long</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should you `overflow: hidden` instead of `overflow: scroll`

Comment: Why? I tried the code and it worked. What different you think it will make?

Comment: To remove the scroll bar at the cell which have content overflowed.

Comment: i need to make it scroll vertically, not horizontally
i tried overflow-y and didnt work